# I keep getting a 400 (Bad Request) when submitting a WordPress form using the Fetch API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, fetch

I am working on a WordPress site and I am trying to convert my jQuery code to vanilla JavaScript (mostly as a learning experience, but also so I don't have to rely on jQuery). The goal is once the form is submitted, instead of going to a thank you page or something else, simply display an overlay over the form saying "Thank you for your message". Again, everything works fine with jQuery/AJAX, but I want to try and get it working with plain JavaScript as well.

Here is the working jQuery code:

```
  jQuery('#myContactForm').on('submit', function () {
    var formData = jQuery(this).serializeArray();

    formData.push({ 
      name: 'security', 
      value: ajaxNonce 
    });

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: ajaxUrl,
      data: formData
    });

    jQuery('.form-overlay').addClass('visible');

    return false;
  });
```

And here is the working code from functions.php:

```
<?php 

function javascript_variables() { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxUrl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    var ajaxNonce = '<?php echo wp_create_nonce('secure_nonce_name'); ?>';
  </script>
  <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'javascript_variables');


add_action('wp_ajax_send_form', 'send_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_form', 'send_form');
 
function send_form() {
  check_ajax_referer('secure_nonce_name', 'security');
 
  $to = 'myemailaddressgoeshere@gmail.com';

  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  
  $body  = 'From: ' . $_POST['full_name'] . '<br />';
  $body .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . '<br />';
  $body .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '<br />';
  $body .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '<br />';

  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    
  wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

  wp_die();
}
```

And finally, here is the relevant input inside the form:

```
<input class="form-inputs" type="hidden" name="action" value="send_form" />
```

Here is what I came up with when trying to use the Fetch API instead of jQuery:

```
// handle form submission
const formSubmissionHandler = () => {
  const form = document.getElementById('myContactForm');
  const formOverlay = document.querySelector('.form-overlay');
  const formInputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.form-inputs'));
  const formData = [];

  form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    formInputs.forEach((input) => {
      if (!input.name || !input.value) {
        return;
      }

      formData.push({
        name: input.name,
        value: input.value,
      });
    });

    formData.push({
      name: 'security',
      value: ajaxNonce,
    });

    const fetchOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    };

    // send post request
    fetch(ajaxUrl, fetchOptions)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));

    formOverlay.classList.add('visible');
  });
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', formSubmissionHandler);
```

I've come across the `FormData()` constructor from searching, not sure where/if I would use that here?

And here is what I wrote in my functions.php file:

```
function send_form() {
  check_ajax_referer('secure_nonce_name', 'security');
 
  $to = 'myemailaddressgoeshere@gmail.com';

  $subject = $_POST['subject'];

  $json_input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

  $body = '';
  
  foreach ($json_input as $key => $value) {
    $body  = 'From: ' . $value['full_name'] . '<br />';
    $body .= 'Email: ' . $value['email'] . '<br />';
    $body .= 'Phone: ' . $value['phone'] . '<br />';
    $body .= 'Message: ' . $value['message'] . '<br />';
  }

  $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    
  wp_mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);

  wp_die();
}
```

I am new to all this so if someone could help me out it would be much appreciated. I think my issue is how I am parsing the JSON data in functions.php. Or could I simply not format the data the same in vanilla JS as it's done in jQuery? Thank you!

Comment: Genuine question out of curiosity: why are you using CSS to "hide" your already hidden `action` input field?

Comment: Also, note that `formInputs` (in your vanilla JS code) is querying only for elements with class `form-inputs`. That leaves out your hidden `action` field, right? Your jQuery version pulls in all fields.

Comment: @cabrerahector I forgot to include the class name form-inputs on the hidden input when I pasted the code in. I have since updated it.

And for the CSS on the hidden input, tbh I am not sure haha. I got most of the code from other articles/tutorials, so I didn't notice it. I've since removed it.

Comment: could you `console.log(ajaxUrl)` before `fetch(ajaxUrl, fetchOptions)` and let me know if you get the right url? One of the 400 Bad Request error triggers is if the URL is incorrect.

Comment: @parse When I `console.log(ajaxUrl)` I get `http://www.domainnamehere.ca/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`

Answer (score 0):

I know it is probably a bit late for me to post this but incase somebody in future runs into this, here is the deal:

```
const fetchOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(formData),
};
```

here, you are making a json string to pass to the destination URL but you have to remember, Wordpress's ajax parser can't understand data being sent to it as raw json.

```
$json_input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

here, you're turning the raw input that you received into an array, but before this, all Wordpress got was a piece of data which is a simple string. So, it doesn't know how to deal with it and what user-defined hook and actions should be fired to validate this.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_send_form', 'send_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_form', 'send_form');
```

here, you are telling wordpress to expect some request with the 'action' name of 'send_form' and if you got it, pass it to a function named 'send_form'. Wordpress however is not recieving that request with the name 'action'. Hence the error.

**The fix**, however, is quite simple, just add this request name as a GET to the url you're sending the raw data to and clear it up for wordpress:

```
var ajaxUrl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>?action=send_for';
```

or, the version I prefer:

```
// send post request
fetch(ajaxUrl + '?action=send_form', fetchOptions)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((res) => console.log(res))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

and done!
I think once you star to work with fetch() and WP, at least for now (untill Wordpress figures out a way), this could come handy.